# Scaling SVG in HTML5

Tags: html, svg

I have replaced a header logo image which was just text in an arc on the following website: [Leeds Magic Circle](http://www.leedsmagiccircle.co.uk)

**Disclaimer:** I did not design or create this website I am just performing some small modifications to it.

The original image said "1919 - 2015" and needed updating, hence I chose SVG to replace it with a bit of javascript to update the date portion.

It looks good, however it doesn't scale down when the browser is reduced or viewed on a mobile device.

I need the SVG to fit the 800x116 which replaced the original image, but I need it to scale down too.

I am very new to playing with SVG and the answers on the web are somewhat confusing so hopefully someone here can help.

Also open to alternative methods to achieve this goal.

Thank you

Comment: adding a valid viewBox attribute should make it scale

Comment: Is that done by just adding something like Viewbox="0 0 800 116"?

Comment: SVG is case sensitive so it's viewBox but yes that's the kind of thing.